# How to switch 2 different outlet circuits in your home easily

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, circuit, internet

I'm trying to connect my PC to the internet using Internet over power. My room's outlets are on a different electrical circuit to the rest of the house. Is there a easy way to switch my rooms outlets with another's so that I can get fast internet speeds?

[image]

Comment: I'm unsure on how to identify the correct breakers

Comment: Yikes! Good thing you were able to upload a picture. This isn't the typical US/Canada setup. I can't give you an answer on this one - out of my area (geographically and technically). Add your country or region to the question as that will (hopefully) help someone else figure out the solution.

Comment: Okay easy thanks for your help anyways!

Comment: Where in the world is this? In a 240v country, everything should be on the same bus. I'd be worried if there's something that's not.

Comment: I am confused. Why would the source of the rooms power effect the internet speeds? Would the net source not be "injected" into the whole house?  If not can the "net" be directed to a certain room? Why would it be only in some rooms in the first place?

Comment: @RMDman I'm certainly no expert on EoP, but I do believe that once the ethernet signal gets to the nearest panel, the signal quality does degrade. So if you plug the router into an outlet on breaker 1, you get a lower quality signal if you plug the receiver into an outlet on breaker 2. Not sure of the physics/electronics involved, though.

Comment: @Harry to identify the breakers in question, turn them off one at a time and find out which outlets/lights/etc lose power when you do. While you're at it, create a nice little map of your house and note which items are on which breaker, then store that near your panel for future reference. Also, plan on resetting a lot of digital clocks...

Comment: @FreeMan this is all foreign to me. Thank for the explaination.

Comment: TBH, if you're not certain how to identify which outlet is on which breaker, swapping an outlet to a different circuit may be diving a bit deep for your first DIY project. Also, I know that the Clipsal brand is sold in Australia (among other places) and I understand that DIY electrical work is verboten in Aus. You will need to check your local rules and regulations to see if you're even allowed to do this yourself. I'm 100% in support of DIY, but this may be a project to hire out - we want you to be able to come back to ask new questions and not "how do I rebuild my burnt down house".